# Google PHP API Client Require Fail (Without using Composer)

Tags: php, google-api-php-client

I downloaded the Google API library from here https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client. I unzipped it and uploaded it to my server at '/etc/'. I then put the path in my script as:

```
require_once '/var/www/html/example.com/etc/google-api-php-client-master/src/Google/autoload.php';
```

This is all per the doc on that page:

> you can download the package in its entirety. The Releases page lists all stable versions. Download any file with the name google-api-php-client-[RELEASE_NAME].zip for a package including this library and its dependencies.
>
> Uncompress the zip file you download, and include the autoloader in your project:
>
> require_once '/path/to/google-api-php-client/vendor/autoload.php';

Server error log:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Exception: This library must be installed via composer or by downloading the full package. See the instructions at https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client#installation. in /var/www/html/example.com/etc/google-api-php-client-master/src/Google/autoload.php:14\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/html/example.com/etc/google_validate.php(2): require_once()\n#1 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/html/example.com/etc/google-api-php-client-master/src/Google/autoload.php on line 14, referer: https://chris-dev2.jove.com/etc/google.html

Did what I do somehow not `download the package in its entirety`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to the [releases](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/releases) page, scroll to the bottom of the latest release and download the .zip asset. Don't choose the PHP54 file unless you explicitly are using PHP 5.4.

[image]

Extract the archive, move it to your project, and include the `vendor/autoload.php` file from the API client archive.

(If you're able to use Composer, it will be a better experience!)